# How can I use nested formulas in the ARRAYFORMULA function in Google Sheets?

Tags: google-sheets, array-formulas

I need Google Sheets to compute sums for each row using the `arrayformula()` function.

I know I can manualy enter somthing like;

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(A:A + B:B + C:C)
```

but I need the use of the functions to do it.

I've tried many things including;

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(sum(A:A,C:C))
```

Here is a [sample file](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/15ehNnTjAbuIUo_KNz363zLXjqlk-0InIspZAQm9yhB8/edit#gid=0) that I could use help with.

Comment: Welcome as an active member of Stack Overflow. Please take the [tour] and checkout [ask].

Answer (score 1):

This formula works in cell G3 of your test sheet:

`=ArrayFormula(mmult(ARRAYFORMULA(IF(ISBLANK(A3:C),0,A3:C)),sign(transpose(column(A3:C)))))`

I've used a custom format to hide the zero values on the empty rows as well

Comment: wahoo! Thank you. That solves my problem when I use sums. 

I'm not sure how I would use this to apply this to other functions though.

For example. How can use arrayformula to perform other functions like concatenate across rows. If you can take a look at the document again I would be greatful.

Comment: within an arrayformula, you need to use the & sign instead of concatenate: =ArrayFormula(I3:I&J3:J&K3:K)

Answer (score 0):

## Formulas

### Addition (SUM)

QUERY function

```
=QUERY(A3:C20,"Select A+B+C Label A+B+C ''")
```

### Concatenation

& operator

```
=ArrayFormula(J3:J20&K3:K20&L3:L20)
```

CONCAT function

```
=ArrayFormula(CONCAT(CONCAT(J3:J20,K3:K20),L3:L20))
```

## Explanation

Besides ARRAYFORMULA, Google Sheets has QUERY, FILTER, ARRAY_CONSTRAIN,  among other functions that could help you to handle array operations. Take a look to [Function List](https://support.google.com/docs/table/25273?hl=es) to have the complete list. Also could be very helpful that you to take a look to [Using arrays in Google Sheets](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/6208276?hl=en).